# C code after preprocessor and constant propagation

Tags: c, gcc, constants, c-preprocessor

I want to get **C** code after going through preprocessor **AND** constant propagation and simple code analysis. Here is what I mean.

I use gcc's `-E` option to get the code after preprocessor. However, the code I am getting is really hard to understand and a simple pass of local constant propagation would make it much easier to read. Here is an example of just one line of **C** code generated by the preprocessor.

```
(b1[0] = (kp + 1 * 4)[0] ^ 
( t_fn[0][(((( 0 == 0 ? ( 0 == 0 ? b0[0] : 0 == 1 ? b0[1] : 0 == 2 ? b0[2] : b0[3]) : 0 == 1 ? ( 0 == 0 ? b0[1] : 0 == 1 ? b0[2] : 0 == 2 ? b0[3] : b0[0]) : 0 == 2 ? ( 0 == 0 ? b0[2] : 0 == 1 ? b0[3] : 0 == 2 ? b0[0] : b0[1]) : ( 0 == 0 ? b0[3] : 0 == 1 ? b0[0] : 0 == 2 ? b0[1] : b0[2]))) >> (8 * ((0)))) & 0xff)] 
^ t_fn[1][(((( 1 == 0 ? ( 0 == 0 ? b0[0] : 0 == 1 ? b0[1] : 0 == 2 ? b0[2] : b0[3]) : 1 == 1 ? ( 0 == 0 ? b0[1] : 0 == 1 ? b0[2] : 0 == 2 ? b0[3] : b0[0]) : 1 == 2 ? ( 0 == 0 ? b0[2] : 0 == 1 ? b0[3] : 0 == 2 ? b0[0] : b0[1]) : ( 0 == 0 ? b0[3] : 0 == 1 ? b0[0] : 0 == 2 ? b0[1] : b0[2]))) >> (8 * ((1)))) & 0xff)] 
^ t_fn[2][(((( 2 == 0 ? ( 0 == 0 ? b0[0] : 0 == 1 ? b0[1] : 0 == 2 ? b0[2] : b0[3]) : 2 == 1 ? ( 0 == 0 ? b0[1] : 0 == 1 ? b0[2] : 0 == 2 ? b0[3] : b0[0]) : 2 == 2 ? ( 0 == 0 ? b0[2] : 0 == 1 ? b0[3] : 0 == 2 ? b0[0] : b0[1]) : ( 0 == 0 ? b0[3] : 0 == 1 ? b0[0] : 0 == 2 ? b0[1] : b0[2]))) >> (8 * ((2)))) & 0xff)] 
^ t_fn[3][(((( 3 == 0 ? ( 0 == 0 ? b0[0] : 0 == 1 ? b0[1] : 0 == 2 ? b0[2] : b0[3]) : 3 == 1 ? ( 0 == 0 ? b0[1] : 0 == 1 ? b0[2] : 0 == 2 ? b0[3] : b0[0]) : 3 == 2 ? ( 0 == 0 ? b0[2] : 0 == 1 ? b0[3] : 0 == 2 ? b0[0] : b0[1]) : ( 0 == 0 ? b0[3] : 0 == 1 ? b0[0] : 0 == 2 ? b0[1] : b0[2]))) >> (8 * ((3)))) & 0xff)]));
```

pieces like `0 == 0 ? X : Y` and  `8*2` can be easily transformed to simpler forms. Now there is tons of such lines in my code and this is a real headache. So it would be great if I could get a simpler **C** code by just doing a simple local constant propagation and code analysis?

Comment: I have a C/C++ source code analysis toolkit and maybe I can help you. Unfortunately it is not really clear what do you want. Can you be more specific?

Comment: So if there is tool that can take this complecited C code (the c code after preprocesser) and outputs simplified C code, then I could say I would be happy. To get simplified code, the tool should be able to do local optimizations such as local constant propagation and optmizing away things that are always true or always false. For example, `0 == 0 ? X : Y` is essentially `X`.

Comment: My tool can take in any C code (it takes it from the file), and do some processing. I can do preprocessor simplification like removing inactive `#ifdef`s. What is constant propagation I do not know. Please, explain.

Comment: putting simply, things like b[5*8] are replaced with b[40].
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding

Comment: I see. Drop me a line with sample file and more detailed info of what do you want to simplify and in what context at http://cdsan.com/Contacts.php. I will check if I can do this in a reasonable time or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you would need a tool that can essentially perform code optimization at source code level. The compiler will not help you here, since compilers do not normally optimize the code at source code level. Any code transformations normally take place much later, when the source code is no longer relevant and there's really no way back to it.

In other words, you would need a tool specifically designed to solve your problem. I'm unaware of any such tool and I doubt it exists.

Comment: Thanks! maybe I should have asked whether or not there is a tool to do local optimization on a C code and output a "transformed" c code.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this with any C compiler I'm aware of. Constant propagation typically occurs after it's already too late to transform the internal representation back into C.

Comment: That makes sense. But is there any tool to do such local optimization on a C code?